# How do I save settings data in processing then load it in later for use

Tags: xml, save, processing

I'm using [processing](http://processing.org/) and [controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) for a project. I have a number of fields that the user fils out. When the user is done, I would like some way to save that data as setting file, preferably as a JSON, XML or Plist file, so it can be loaded back in at a later time. What is the best way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

For a settings file I would recommend using the [`saveXML()`](https://processing.org/reference/saveXML_.html), [`loadXML()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadXML_.html) and [`parseXML()`](https://processing.org/reference/parseXML_.html) function of processing.

Answer (score 0):

for offline use, you should be able to saveStrings() and loadStrings(). As long as you have written a settings object that has a toString() function, and a constructor that can build itself from that kind of string (so t.equals(new Thing(t.toString()) is true) you can write and read the serialized version to disk.